# Are there any Catholic directives (rubrics) from the 17th to 19th century about what to do/pray/think during Eucharist Adoration?

Tags: catholicism, liturgy, rubrics, eucharistic-adoration

Are there any Catholic directives (some kind of manual or rubrics) from the 17th to 19th century about what to do/pray/think during Eucharist Adoration?

Comment: Learn about 9 grades of prayer: http://catholic-church.org/grace/growing/9grades/9grades.htm.

Answer (score 1):

The [Saint-Pierre de Solesmes Benedictine abbey](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeYr74GiVdPB2ePM6eRSYiw)—founded by [Dom Guéranger, O.S.B.](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DGu%C3%A9ranger%2C%20Prosper%2C%20O.S.B.%22), who reestablished, in the 19<sup>th</sup> century, the Benedictine order and Gregorian chant in France after its destruction by the French Revolution—published a [*Cantus Selecti ad Benedictionem SS.mi Sacramenti*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3881) (1957) whose 7<sup>th</sup> and 8<sup>th</sup> chapters are entitled *Ante Benedictionem* and *Post Benedictionem*, respectively. Most [pre-Vatican II missals](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_list&search=title:missal%20language:latin) (such as [this one](https://angeluspress.org/products/1962-roman-catholic-daily-missal)) have a section with benediction prayers and hymns, too.

Comment: The question deals with [Eucharistic Adoration](http://www.catholic-church.org/kuwait/eucharistic_adoration.htm), more than [Benediction](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=32142) of the Holy Eucharist. Benediction and Eucharistic Adoration may or may not be be part the same liturgical function, according to the circumstances at a particular point in time.